# Google API set Multi Dimensional Polygon

Tags: google-maps, multidimensional-array, polygons

I am trying to set Multiple Polygons to a Google map from an array.  The array is passed into the view from the Control via a database WKT value as you can see in the example. Everything works except getting it to create individual polygons.

The issue I am running into is that I cannot seem to get it to draw individual Polygons.  It draws one, then moves on the next but does not break and start a new one.  The number of points and number of Polygons will vary almost every time the page is loaded, they are not static Polygons.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var newArr = [];
            var FinishedPoly = [];
            var doubleLayer = [];
            var Completed = [];
            var i = 0;
            var PolygonOut = { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-90.968107709266562, 38.099441706209241], [-90.967945223634572, 38.099447106988919], [-90.967783246532832, 38.099458604972995], [-90.967622144142851, 38.099476174167982], [-90.9674622806693, 38.099499774855182], [-90.967304017516966, 38.099529353680481], [-90.96714771247396, 38.099564843774878], [-90.966993718903126, 38.099606164905637], [-90.966842384943376, 38.099653223657619], [-90.966694052722886, 38.099705913644364], [-90.966549057585866, 38.09976411574857], [-90.966407727334541, 38.099827698391294], [-90.966270381488286, 38.099896517829265], [-90.966137330561338, 38.099970418479884], [-90.96600887536097, 38.100049233272728], [-90.965885306307413, 38.100132784027231], [-90.965766902777432, 38.100220881855364], [-90.965653932472634, 38.100313327588573], [-90.965546650814275, 38.10040991222796], [-90.965445300365758, 38.100510417416608], [-90.965350110284135, 38.100614615933246], [-90.965261295801952, 38.100722272205715], [-90.965179057740443, 38.100833142843541], [-90.9651035820554, 38.100946977188066], [-90.96503503941652, 38.101063517879027], [-90.964973584821365, 38.101182501436348], [-90.964919357244582, 38.101303658855713], [-90.964872479323546, 38.101426716216707], [-90.96483305708071, 38.101551395302018], [-90.964801179683647, 38.101677414226373], [-90.964776919243064, 38.10180448807386], [-90.964760330649483, 38.101932329541988], [-90.964751451448748, 38.102060649591252], [-90.956501934838812, 38.310868546056618], [-90.95650085334276, 38.311001194985508], [-90.956508034151412, 38.311133725939143], [-90.956523460010317, 38.311265819630947], [-90.956547093801035, 38.311397157826029], [-90.956578878630054, 38.311527424107915], [-90.9566187379655, 38.311656304640842], [-90.956666575821032, 38.311783488925961], [-90.9567222769867, 38.311908670549414], [-90.956785707306253, 38.312031547920576], [-90.956856713999841, 38.312151824998814], [-90.956935126031908, 38.312269212006761], [-90.95702075452283, 38.312383426128591], [-90.957113393203812, 38.312494192191437], [-90.957212818913547, 38.312601243328544], [-90.9573187921357, 38.312704321622306], [-90.957431057575775, 38.312803178725758], [-90.9575493447761, 38.312897576461154], [-90.957673368767288, 38.3129872873938], [-90.957802830754858, 38.313072095380242], [-90.957937418839009, 38.313151796089087], [-90.958076808766137, 38.313226197493506], [-90.958220664710211, 38.313295120333969], [-90.958368640081815, 38.313358398550264], [-90.9585203783635, 38.313415879681735], [-90.958675513968856, 38.313467425234684], [-90.958833673123465, 38.313512911016204], [-90.9589944747658, 38.313552227433455], [-90.959157531465507, 38.313585279757838], [-90.959322450357149, 38.313611988353237], [-90.959488834087068, 38.313632288868057], [-90.959656281771061, 38.313646132390247], [-90.959824389960588, 38.313653485565204], [-90.95999275361514, 38.313654330676158], [-90.960160967078508, 38.313648665686905], [-90.96032862505642, 38.313636504246695], [-90.96049532359352, 38.3136178756573], [-90.960660661046816, 38.313592824802456], [-90.960824239053878, 38.313561412039647], [-90.960985663492792, 38.313523713054643], [-90.9611445454322, 38.313479818679042], [-90.961300502068511, 38.313429834671439], [-90.961453157648549, 38.313373881462446], [-90.961602144375092, 38.313312093864489], [-90.961747103293234, 38.313244620746879], [-90.961887685155361, 38.313171624677032], [-90.962023551262817, 38.313093281528666], [-90.962154374281965, 38.313009780057953], [-90.962279839032988, 38.3129213214486], [-90.962399643249213, 38.312828118826992], [-90.962513498305455, 38.312730396748634], [-90.962621129913259, 38.312628390656926], [-90.962722278781726, 38.312522346315795], [-90.9628167012421, 38.312412519217482], [-90.962904169834644, 38.312299173966849], [-90.962984473856466, 38.31218258364369], [-90.96305741986896, 38.312063029144809], [-90.963122832163577, 38.311940798507052], [-90.963180553184813, 38.311816186213306], [-90.963230443909538, 38.311689492482934], [-90.96327238418155, 38.311561022548375], [-90.96330627300074, 38.311431085919686], [-90.963332028765933, 38.311299995638855], [-90.963349589471193, 38.311168067525557], [-90.963358912854687, 38.311035619416181], [-90.971588888328952, 38.102227246362872], [-90.971589839404146, 38.102090447347592], [-90.971582029203063, 38.10195378554414], [-90.971565477784637, 38.101817611082176], [-90.971540227602333, 38.101682272840854], [-90.9715063433949, 38.101548117555019], [-90.971463912020027, 38.1014154889269], [-90.971413042231362, 38.101284726745618], [-90.97135386439939, 38.101156166016786], [-90.971286530177068, 38.101030136104235], [-90.971211212110859, 38.100906959886352], [-90.971128103198311, 38.100786952928992], [-90.971037416393344, 38.100670422677155], [-90.970939384060244, 38.100557667667452], [-90.970834257378286, 38.1004489767634], [-90.97072230569789, 38.100344628415613], [-90.970603815850453, 38.100244889948478], [-90.970479091413424, 38.100150016875546], [-90.970348451932466, 38.100060252245065], [-90.970212232102782, 38.09997582601747], [-90.970070780911712, 38.099896954476463], [-90.9699244607447, 38.09982383967499], [-90.969773646457114, 38.099756668917827], [-90.969618724413948, 38.0996956142819], [-90.969460091500267, 38.099640832175496], [-90.969298154104678, 38.099592462937821], [-90.969133327078524, 38.099550630479456], [-90.968966032673322, 38.099515441965139], [-90.968796699459418, 38.099486987539258], [-90.968625761228381, 38.099465340095023], [-90.9684536558821, 38.099450555087778], [-90.968280824311307, 38.099442670392982], [-90.968107709266562, 38.099441706209241]], [[-90.678323452631432, 37.999953737944836], [-90.678166455726412, 37.999959594774936], [-90.678009965494056, 37.99997116027825], [-90.677854313259544, 37.999988409968019], [-90.6776998285744, 38.00001130732273], [-90.677546838518992, 38.000039803863437], [-90.677395667010231, 38.000073839256387], [-90.677246634116017, 38.000113341440695], [-90.677100055377679, 38.0001582267809], [-90.676956241142179, 38.000208400243935], [-90.67681549590516, 38.0002637556003], [-90.676678117666356, 38.000324175648927], [-90.676544397298827, 38.000389532465249], [-90.676414617933233, 38.0004596876719], [-90.676289054358378, 38.00053449273171], [-90.676167972439544, 38.00061378926209], [-90.67605162855557, 38.000697409370211], [-90.675940269056085, 38.000785176008463], [-90.67583412973984, 38.00087690334923], [-90.675733435355482, 38.000972397178209], [-90.675638399125617, 38.001071455305521], [-90.675549222295217, 38.001173867993757], [-90.675466093705438, 38.001279418401992], [-90.6753891893937, 38.001387883044721], [-90.675318672220655, 38.00149903226508], [-90.6752546915254, 38.001612630720977], [-90.6751973828088, 38.001728437883315], [-90.675146867446614, 38.001846208545231], [-90.675103252432081, 38.001965693341241], [-90.675066630149217, 38.002086639275127], [-90.675037078176885, 38.002208790255658], [-90.6750146591243, 38.002331887638761], [-90.674999420498054, 38.002455670775106], [-90.639276413897491, 38.378067481029881], [-90.639267996619338, 38.378199965586916], [-90.6392678479397, 38.378332615670367], [-90.639275968262183, 38.378465111708238], [-90.639292338069083, 38.3785971344979], [-90.6393169179679, 38.378728365975149], [-90.639349648785839, 38.378858489980431], [-90.639390451711947, 38.378987193020642], [-90.63943922848658, 38.379114165024362], [-90.6394958616377, 38.379239100089016], [-90.639560214763549, 38.37936169721786], [-90.639632132860925, 38.379481661045261], [-90.639711442698285, 38.379598702548428], [-90.639797953232815, 38.379712539743771], [-90.6398914560704, 38.379822898366442], [-90.639991725967491, 38.379929512531163], [-90.6400985213736, 38.380032125373006], [-90.640211585013049, 38.380130489666328], [-90.640330644504786, 38.380224368420556], [-90.640455413018387, 38.380313535451322], [-90.640585589965255, 38.380397775925488], [-90.64072086172267, 38.380476886878952], [-90.640860902389548, 38.380550677705692], [-90.641005374571591, 38.380618970617213], [-90.641153930194392, 38.380681601070975], [-90.641306211342126, 38.380738418166963], [-90.641461851120113, 38.380789285011353], [-90.641620474538939, 38.380834079046444], [-90.6417816994182, 38.380872692346067], [-90.641945137307559, 38.38090503187567], [-90.642110394422971, 38.380931019716563], [-90.642277072595647, 38.380950593253672], [-90.642444770231819, 38.380963705326529], [-90.64261308328058, 38.380970324342883], [-90.642781606207777, 38.380970434354857], [-90.64294993297338, 38.380964035097385], [-90.643117658010141, 38.380951141988859], [-90.643284377201127, 38.380931786093967], [-90.643449688853721, 38.380906014048776], [-90.64361319466768, 38.380873887948432], [-90.643774500695244, 38.380835485197387], [-90.643933218290485, 38.380790898322914], [-90.644088965046038, 38.380740234752047], [-90.644241365714677, 38.380683616552737], [-90.644390053113625, 38.380621180139613], [-90.644534669009488, 38.380553075945166], [-90.644674864981468, 38.380479468057281], [-90.644810303261025, 38.3804005338237], [-90.644940657545717, 38.380316463424677], [-90.645065613785476, 38.380227459414577], [-90.645184870939246, 38.380133736233795], [-90.645298141700337, 38.380035519691894], [-90.6454051531885, 38.379933046423517], [-90.645505647607351, 38.379826563318048], [-90.64559938286537, 38.379716326924708], [-90.645686133158918, 38.379602602834311], [-90.645765689516153, 38.379485665039255], [-90.645837860300233, 38.379365795273316], [-90.645902471670723, 38.37924328233273], [-90.645959368002181, 38.379118421380348], [-90.646008412258709, 38.378991513234389], [-90.646049486323818, 38.378862863643654], [-90.646082491284531, 38.378732782550841], [-90.646107347669428, 38.378601583345741], [-90.646123995639556, 38.378469582110185], [-90.681812121406509, 38.002855712080027], [-90.681820663991914, 38.002714926225892], [-90.681819919332568, 38.00257397942601], [-90.681809889507221, 38.002433255001819], [-90.681790601846274, 38.002293135667749], [-90.681762108857114, 38.002154002490506], [-90.681724488080533, 38.0020162338527], [-90.681677841879477, 38.001880204423841], [-90.681622297159976, 38.001746284141554], [-90.681558005025579, 38.001614837205537], [-90.681485140366, 38.001486221087255], [-90.6814039013809, 38.001360785557871], [-90.681314509040632, 38.001238871737193], [-90.681217206484831, 38.001120811166146], [-90.681112258360969, 38.00100692490529], [-90.68099995010428, 38.000897522661859], [-90.680880587161411, 38.000792901947776], [-90.680754494159544, 38.000693347270605], [-90.68062201402347, 38.000599129360154], [-90.680483507043007, 38.000510504432384], [-90.68033934989316, 38.00042771349279], [-90.680189934609885, 38.000350981681244], [-90.68003566752401, 38.00028051765986], [-90.679876968156492, 38.000216513045771], [-90.679714268077731, 38.000159141890137], [-90.679548009734148, 38.000108560205049], [-90.679378645245421, 38.000064905539347], [-90.679206635175163, 38.000028296604739], [-90.679032447278956, 37.99999883295304], [-90.678856555232727, 37.999976594705572], [-90.678679437344954, 37.999961642335386], [-90.678501575256547, 37.999954016502777], [-90.678323452631432, 37.999953737944836]]]};
            var doubleLayer = PolygonOut.coordinates;

            $(document).ready(function CleanIt() {
                for (var s = 0; s < doubleLayer.length; s++) {

                    for (var i = doubleLayer[s].length; i--;) {
                        var temp = doubleLayer[s][i][0];

                        doubleLayer[s][i][0] = doubleLayer[s][i][1];
                        doubleLayer[s][i][1] = temp;

                    }


                    for (var t = 0; t < doubleLayer[s].length; t++)
                    {
                        var Coords = [];
                        newArr = newArr.concat(doubleLayer[s][t]);
                        FinishedPoly[s] = newArr;

                        for (var p = 0; p < FinishedPoly.length; p++)
                        {
                            for (var j = 0, g = 0; j < FinishedPoly[p].length; j++, g++)
                            { 
                                Coords = new google.maps.LatLng(FinishedPoly[p][j], FinishedPoly[p][j + 1]);

                                j++;
                                Completed[g] = Coords;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    var compPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: Completed,
                        strokeColor: '#e88e19',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#247fb8',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35
                    });
                    compPoly.setMap(map);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var newArr = [];
            var FinishedPoly = [];
            var doubleLayer = [];
            var Completed = [];
            var Coords = [];
            var i = 0;
            var PolygonOut = { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-90.968107709266562, 38.099441706209241], [-90.967945223634572, 38.099447106988919], [-90.967783246532832, 38.099458604972995], [-90.967622144142851, 38.099476174167982], [-90.9674622806693, 38.099499774855182], [-90.967304017516966, 38.099529353680481], [-90.96714771247396, 38.099564843774878], [-90.966993718903126, 38.099606164905637], [-90.966842384943376, 38.099653223657619], [-90.966694052722886, 38.099705913644364], [-90.966549057585866, 38.09976411574857], [-90.966407727334541, 38.099827698391294], [-90.966270381488286, 38.099896517829265], [-90.966137330561338, 38.099970418479884], [-90.96600887536097, 38.100049233272728], [-90.965885306307413, 38.100132784027231], [-90.965766902777432, 38.100220881855364], [-90.965653932472634, 38.100313327588573], [-90.965546650814275, 38.10040991222796], [-90.965445300365758, 38.100510417416608], [-90.965350110284135, 38.100614615933246], [-90.965261295801952, 38.100722272205715], [-90.965179057740443, 38.100833142843541], [-90.9651035820554, 38.100946977188066], [-90.96503503941652, 38.101063517879027], [-90.964973584821365, 38.101182501436348], [-90.964919357244582, 38.101303658855713], [-90.964872479323546, 38.101426716216707], [-90.96483305708071, 38.101551395302018], [-90.964801179683647, 38.101677414226373], [-90.964776919243064, 38.10180448807386], [-90.964760330649483, 38.101932329541988], [-90.964751451448748, 38.102060649591252], [-90.956501934838812, 38.310868546056618], [-90.95650085334276, 38.311001194985508], [-90.956508034151412, 38.311133725939143], [-90.956523460010317, 38.311265819630947], [-90.956547093801035, 38.311397157826029], [-90.956578878630054, 38.311527424107915], [-90.9566187379655, 38.311656304640842], [-90.956666575821032, 38.311783488925961], [-90.9567222769867, 38.311908670549414], [-90.956785707306253, 38.312031547920576], [-90.956856713999841, 38.312151824998814], [-90.956935126031908, 38.312269212006761], [-90.95702075452283, 38.312383426128591], [-90.957113393203812, 38.312494192191437], [-90.957212818913547, 38.312601243328544], [-90.9573187921357, 38.312704321622306], [-90.957431057575775, 38.312803178725758], [-90.9575493447761, 38.312897576461154], [-90.957673368767288, 38.3129872873938], [-90.957802830754858, 38.313072095380242], [-90.957937418839009, 38.313151796089087], [-90.958076808766137, 38.313226197493506], [-90.958220664710211, 38.313295120333969], [-90.958368640081815, 38.313358398550264], [-90.9585203783635, 38.313415879681735], [-90.958675513968856, 38.313467425234684], [-90.958833673123465, 38.313512911016204], [-90.9589944747658, 38.313552227433455], [-90.959157531465507, 38.313585279757838], [-90.959322450357149, 38.313611988353237], [-90.959488834087068, 38.313632288868057], [-90.959656281771061, 38.313646132390247], [-90.959824389960588, 38.313653485565204], [-90.95999275361514, 38.313654330676158], [-90.960160967078508, 38.313648665686905], [-90.96032862505642, 38.313636504246695], [-90.96049532359352, 38.3136178756573], [-90.960660661046816, 38.313592824802456], [-90.960824239053878, 38.313561412039647], [-90.960985663492792, 38.313523713054643], [-90.9611445454322, 38.313479818679042], [-90.961300502068511, 38.313429834671439], [-90.961453157648549, 38.313373881462446], [-90.961602144375092, 38.313312093864489], [-90.961747103293234, 38.313244620746879], [-90.961887685155361, 38.313171624677032], [-90.962023551262817, 38.313093281528666], [-90.962154374281965, 38.313009780057953], [-90.962279839032988, 38.3129213214486], [-90.962399643249213, 38.312828118826992], [-90.962513498305455, 38.312730396748634], [-90.962621129913259, 38.312628390656926], [-90.962722278781726, 38.312522346315795], [-90.9628167012421, 38.312412519217482], [-90.962904169834644, 38.312299173966849], [-90.962984473856466, 38.31218258364369], [-90.96305741986896, 38.312063029144809], [-90.963122832163577, 38.311940798507052], [-90.963180553184813, 38.311816186213306], [-90.963230443909538, 38.311689492482934], [-90.96327238418155, 38.311561022548375], [-90.96330627300074, 38.311431085919686], [-90.963332028765933, 38.311299995638855], [-90.963349589471193, 38.311168067525557], [-90.963358912854687, 38.311035619416181], [-90.971588888328952, 38.102227246362872], [-90.971589839404146, 38.102090447347592], [-90.971582029203063, 38.10195378554414], [-90.971565477784637, 38.101817611082176], [-90.971540227602333, 38.101682272840854], [-90.9715063433949, 38.101548117555019], [-90.971463912020027, 38.1014154889269], [-90.971413042231362, 38.101284726745618], [-90.97135386439939, 38.101156166016786], [-90.971286530177068, 38.101030136104235], [-90.971211212110859, 38.100906959886352], [-90.971128103198311, 38.100786952928992], [-90.971037416393344, 38.100670422677155], [-90.970939384060244, 38.100557667667452], [-90.970834257378286, 38.1004489767634], [-90.97072230569789, 38.100344628415613], [-90.970603815850453, 38.100244889948478], [-90.970479091413424, 38.100150016875546], [-90.970348451932466, 38.100060252245065], [-90.970212232102782, 38.09997582601747], [-90.970070780911712, 38.099896954476463], [-90.9699244607447, 38.09982383967499], [-90.969773646457114, 38.099756668917827], [-90.969618724413948, 38.0996956142819], [-90.969460091500267, 38.099640832175496], [-90.969298154104678, 38.099592462937821], [-90.969133327078524, 38.099550630479456], [-90.968966032673322, 38.099515441965139], [-90.968796699459418, 38.099486987539258], [-90.968625761228381, 38.099465340095023], [-90.9684536558821, 38.099450555087778], [-90.968280824311307, 38.099442670392982], [-90.968107709266562, 38.099441706209241]], [[-90.678323452631432, 37.999953737944836], [-90.678166455726412, 37.999959594774936], [-90.678009965494056, 37.99997116027825], [-90.677854313259544, 37.999988409968019], [-90.6776998285744, 38.00001130732273], [-90.677546838518992, 38.000039803863437], [-90.677395667010231, 38.000073839256387], [-90.677246634116017, 38.000113341440695], [-90.677100055377679, 38.0001582267809], [-90.676956241142179, 38.000208400243935], [-90.67681549590516, 38.0002637556003], [-90.676678117666356, 38.000324175648927], [-90.676544397298827, 38.000389532465249], [-90.676414617933233, 38.0004596876719], [-90.676289054358378, 38.00053449273171], [-90.676167972439544, 38.00061378926209], [-90.67605162855557, 38.000697409370211], [-90.675940269056085, 38.000785176008463], [-90.67583412973984, 38.00087690334923], [-90.675733435355482, 38.000972397178209], [-90.675638399125617, 38.001071455305521], [-90.675549222295217, 38.001173867993757], [-90.675466093705438, 38.001279418401992], [-90.6753891893937, 38.001387883044721], [-90.675318672220655, 38.00149903226508], [-90.6752546915254, 38.001612630720977], [-90.6751973828088, 38.001728437883315], [-90.675146867446614, 38.001846208545231], [-90.675103252432081, 38.001965693341241], [-90.675066630149217, 38.002086639275127], [-90.675037078176885, 38.002208790255658], [-90.6750146591243, 38.002331887638761], [-90.674999420498054, 38.002455670775106], [-90.639276413897491, 38.378067481029881], [-90.639267996619338, 38.378199965586916], [-90.6392678479397, 38.378332615670367], [-90.639275968262183, 38.378465111708238], [-90.639292338069083, 38.3785971344979], [-90.6393169179679, 38.378728365975149], [-90.639349648785839, 38.378858489980431], [-90.639390451711947, 38.378987193020642], [-90.63943922848658, 38.379114165024362], [-90.6394958616377, 38.379239100089016], [-90.639560214763549, 38.37936169721786], [-90.639632132860925, 38.379481661045261], [-90.639711442698285, 38.379598702548428], [-90.639797953232815, 38.379712539743771], [-90.6398914560704, 38.379822898366442], [-90.639991725967491, 38.379929512531163], [-90.6400985213736, 38.380032125373006], [-90.640211585013049, 38.380130489666328], [-90.640330644504786, 38.380224368420556], [-90.640455413018387, 38.380313535451322], [-90.640585589965255, 38.380397775925488], [-90.64072086172267, 38.380476886878952], [-90.640860902389548, 38.380550677705692], [-90.641005374571591, 38.380618970617213], [-90.641153930194392, 38.380681601070975], [-90.641306211342126, 38.380738418166963], [-90.641461851120113, 38.380789285011353], [-90.641620474538939, 38.380834079046444], [-90.6417816994182, 38.380872692346067], [-90.641945137307559, 38.38090503187567], [-90.642110394422971, 38.380931019716563], [-90.642277072595647, 38.380950593253672], [-90.642444770231819, 38.380963705326529], [-90.64261308328058, 38.380970324342883], [-90.642781606207777, 38.380970434354857], [-90.64294993297338, 38.380964035097385], [-90.643117658010141, 38.380951141988859], [-90.643284377201127, 38.380931786093967], [-90.643449688853721, 38.380906014048776], [-90.64361319466768, 38.380873887948432], [-90.643774500695244, 38.380835485197387], [-90.643933218290485, 38.380790898322914], [-90.644088965046038, 38.380740234752047], [-90.644241365714677, 38.380683616552737], [-90.644390053113625, 38.380621180139613], [-90.644534669009488, 38.380553075945166], [-90.644674864981468, 38.380479468057281], [-90.644810303261025, 38.3804005338237], [-90.644940657545717, 38.380316463424677], [-90.645065613785476, 38.380227459414577], [-90.645184870939246, 38.380133736233795], [-90.645298141700337, 38.380035519691894], [-90.6454051531885, 38.379933046423517], [-90.645505647607351, 38.379826563318048], [-90.64559938286537, 38.379716326924708], [-90.645686133158918, 38.379602602834311], [-90.645765689516153, 38.379485665039255], [-90.645837860300233, 38.379365795273316], [-90.645902471670723, 38.37924328233273], [-90.645959368002181, 38.379118421380348], [-90.646008412258709, 38.378991513234389], [-90.646049486323818, 38.378862863643654], [-90.646082491284531, 38.378732782550841], [-90.646107347669428, 38.378601583345741], [-90.646123995639556, 38.378469582110185], [-90.681812121406509, 38.002855712080027], [-90.681820663991914, 38.002714926225892], [-90.681819919332568, 38.00257397942601], [-90.681809889507221, 38.002433255001819], [-90.681790601846274, 38.002293135667749], [-90.681762108857114, 38.002154002490506], [-90.681724488080533, 38.0020162338527], [-90.681677841879477, 38.001880204423841], [-90.681622297159976, 38.001746284141554], [-90.681558005025579, 38.001614837205537], [-90.681485140366, 38.001486221087255], [-90.6814039013809, 38.001360785557871], [-90.681314509040632, 38.001238871737193], [-90.681217206484831, 38.001120811166146], [-90.681112258360969, 38.00100692490529], [-90.68099995010428, 38.000897522661859], [-90.680880587161411, 38.000792901947776], [-90.680754494159544, 38.000693347270605], [-90.68062201402347, 38.000599129360154], [-90.680483507043007, 38.000510504432384], [-90.68033934989316, 38.00042771349279], [-90.680189934609885, 38.000350981681244], [-90.68003566752401, 38.00028051765986], [-90.679876968156492, 38.000216513045771], [-90.679714268077731, 38.000159141890137], [-90.679548009734148, 38.000108560205049], [-90.679378645245421, 38.000064905539347], [-90.679206635175163, 38.000028296604739], [-90.679032447278956, 37.99999883295304], [-90.678856555232727, 37.999976594705572], [-90.678679437344954, 37.999961642335386], [-90.678501575256547, 37.999954016502777], [-90.678323452631432, 37.999953737944836]]]};
            var doubleLayer = PolygonOut.coordinates;

            $(document).ready(function CleanIt() {

                for (var s = 0; s < doubleLayer.length; s++)
                {

                    for (var i = doubleLayer[s].length; i--;)
                    {
                        var temp = doubleLayer[s][i][0];

                        doubleLayer[s][i][0] = doubleLayer[s][i][1];
                        doubleLayer[s][i][1] = temp;
                        doubleLayer[s][i] = new google.maps.LatLng(doubleLayer[s][i][0], doubleLayer[s][i][1]);
                        doubleLayer[s].concat(doubleLayer[i]);
                    }

                }

                var compPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: doubleLayer,
                  strokeColor: '#e88e19',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                  strokeWeight: 2,
                  fillColor: '#247fb8',
                  fillOpacity: 0.35
              });
              compPoly.setMap(map);
            });
            </script>
```